# Write a specific Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I'm pretty new to Lagrangian mechanics, and after some thoery I'm facing the first exercises, as the following:

> Consider a p.particle $P$ of mass $m$ which is constrained to a semi-circle of radius $R$ of equation $x^2+z^2=R^2$, where $z<0$, under the action of the gravity.
>
> Write then the Lagrangian of the system using $x$ as Lagrangan coordinate.

*My solution*

Since the text asks for use $x$ as Lagrangian coordinate, I think to express the $z$-coordinate as a function of $x$, and from the equation of the (semi) circle, I get $z=-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$

Then, I write the Kinetic energy $T(x,\dot x)=\frac{1}{2}m \dot z^2=\frac{1}{2}m \frac{\dot x^2 x^2}{R^2-x^2}$

while the potential energy $V(x)$ I assume to be simply $V(x)=-m g z(x)=+mg\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$

So, the Lagrangian would be $L(x,\dot x)=\frac{1}{2}m \frac{\dot x^2 x^2}{R^2-x^2}+mg\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$

Now, writing the Lagrange equations is just a matter of computations. I'd like to know if I moved correctly, or if I am completely wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a term in the kinetic energy. You should have

$$T=\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}=\frac{1}{2}m\left(\dot{x}^{2}+\dot{z}^{2}\right)$$

since $\boldsymbol{v}=\dot{x}\hat{x}+\dot{z}\hat{z}$.

As for you potential term, the gravitational energy increases with height

$$V=mgz$$

Finally, note that $\mathcal{L}=T-V$ (you used + instead).

Comment: thanks,  but I can't understand why you used the $z$-coordinate. The text just said to use $x$

Comment: @VoB Then substitute $z=z\left(x\right)$. Just said you have the wrong sign.

Comment: Okay, but in any case I have also to consider the kinetic energy with $(\dot x^2 + \dot z^2)$ ? I mean, I missed a term in my solution, right?

Comment: @VoB Exactly. You considered only the velocity in the $z$ direction, ignoring the velocity in the $x$ direction.

Comment: Okay, thanks! One last thing: with $z(x)$ you mean $z(x)=- \sqrt{R^2-x^2}$, as in my solution, right?

Comment: @VoB Indeed! Putting this expression instead of $z$ is one way to incorporate constraints into your Lagrangian. The other way uses Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Okay, perfect! :) Many thanks